# XML links are not loading from an exported HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

First off, I'd like to state that I'm not a web developer or programmer.  I have very little code knowledge.  I'm just a tech support agent trying to solve an issue for a user.

The issue is that we have a vendor application that provides some data in XML format, which renders fine on the web application, but when exported to an HTML file, the links within that file do not work.  The links are supposed to display the XML data.

In IE11, when clicking on any link, it says "The webpage cannot be displayed" with the likely cause being that "Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed."  Also, all of the XML tags and data show up in the address bar.

In Edge, it says "Hmmm...can't reach this page" with an error code of 0x80704006.

In Firefox and Chrome, it appears to try to open another tab, but that quickly disappears.

In Opera, it just shows a blank untitled tab

In Safari on a Macbook, it displays the XML values in the body, but none of the tags.

I tested this on my work Windows 10 laptop as well as a fresh install of Windows 7 both before (IE8) and after (IE11) updates were installed, all with the same results.  Therefore, I don't believe it's anything configured on our images or any policies being pushed that is causing the issue.

I've disabled popup blockers and tried the browsers in safe mode to no avail.

The one user who I'm working with on this is able to view the XML output just fine on his personal Macbook, but only with Firefox, and currently he's using version 57.0.4.

I've looked at the code and have spent hours researching this on the internet, but given my lack of knowledge on this topic, much of what I found has not made much sense to me.

Here's some of the code, which I believe is most relevant to the issue.  There may be nothing wrong with the code, but if someone could take a look and let me know, that would be great.  I can provide the full file if that would be better.  I just didn't see an option to upload it.

```
function urldecode(str) {
return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}

function updateEventMessage(str){
var content = urldecode(str);
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for MSIE x.x;
 var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
 if (ieversion>=9)
  ;//document.write("You're using IE9 or above")
 else if (ieversion>=8)
  ;//document.write("You're using IE8 or above")
 else if (ieversion>=7)
  ;//document.write("You're using IE7.x")
 else if (ieversion>=6)
  ;//document.write("You're using IE6.x")
 else if (ieversion>=5)
  ;//document.write("You're using IE5.x")
  var wxml = window.open("","xml");
  wxml.document.open("text/plain");
  wxml.document.write(content);
  wxml.document.close();
}
else{
    //none ie Browser
    window.open("data:text/xml,"+content); 
}
```

This is the first line from one of the links, which shows the XML tags and data:

```
<tr><td  rowspan='2' colspan='1' class ='sqd_timestr' width='240' align='right'>2018-05-07&nbsp;09:59:58.371</td><td rowspan='2' width='2'>&nbsp;</td><td  rowspan='2' class ='sqd_rightedge width='2'>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan='2' class=sqd_left-arrow width='2'><img class=sqd_left-arrow src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==' width='1' height='1' /></td><td class=sqd_bottomedge width='20'>&nbsp;</td><td class='sqd_bottomedge sqd_msg1' align='center' width='320'><a href='javascript:updateEventMessage("%3CDL-CCCH-Message%3E++%3Cmessage%3E++++%3Cc1%3E++++++%3CrrcConnectionSetup%3E++++++++%3Crrc-TransactionIdentifier%3E0%3C%2Frrc-TransactionIdentifier%3E++++++++%3CcriticalExtensions%3E++++++++++%3Cc1%3E++++++++++++%3CrrcConnectionSetup-r8%3E++++++++++++++%3CradioResourceConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++%3Csrb-ToAddModList%3E++++++++++++++++++%3CSRB-ToAddMod%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Csrb-Identity%3E1%3C%2Fsrb-Identity%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Crlc-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cam%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cul-AM-RLC%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ct-PollRetransmit%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cms45%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Ft-PollRetransmit%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CpollPDU%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CpInfinity%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FpollPDU%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CpollByte%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CkBinfinity%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FpollByte%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CmaxRetxThreshold%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ct32%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FmaxRetxThreshold%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Ful-AM-RLC%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cdl-AM-RLC%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ct-Reordering%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cms35%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Ft-Reordering%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ct-StatusProhibit%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cms0%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Ft-StatusProhibit%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fdl-AM-RLC%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fam%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Frlc-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3ClogicalChannelConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CdefaultValue%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FlogicalChannelConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FSRB-ToAddMod%3E++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fsrb-ToAddModList%3E++++++++++++++++%3Cmac-MainConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++%3CexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Cul-SCH-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CmaxHARQ-Tx%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cn4%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FmaxHARQ-Tx%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CperiodicBSR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csf5%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FperiodicBSR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CretxBSR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csf320%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FretxBSR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CttiBundling%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cfalse%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FttiBundling%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Ful-SCH-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CtimeAlignmentTimerDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cinfinity%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FtimeAlignmentTimerDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Cphr-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csetup%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CperiodicPHR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csf200%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FperiodicPHR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CprohibitPHR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csf200%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FprohibitPHR-Timer%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cdl-PathlossChange%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CdB3%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fdl-PathlossChange%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fsetup%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fphr-Config%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fmac-MainConfig%3E++++++++++++++++%3CphysicalConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++%3Cpdsch-ConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Cp-a%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CdB0%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fp-a%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fpdsch-ConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++%3Cpusch-ConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CbetaOffset-ACK-Index%3E10%3C%2FbetaOffset-ACK-Index%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CbetaOffset-RI-Index%3E9%3C%2FbetaOffset-RI-Index%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CbetaOffset-CQI-Index%3E10%3C%2FbetaOffset-CQI-Index%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fpusch-ConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-ReportConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-ReportModeAperiodic%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Crm30%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fcqi-ReportModeAperiodic%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CnomPDSCH-RS-EPRE-Offset%3E0%3C%2FnomPDSCH-RS-EPRE-Offset%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-ReportPeriodic%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csetup%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-PUCCH-ResourceIndex%3E0%3C%2Fcqi-PUCCH-ResourceIndex%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-pmi-ConfigIndex%3E133%3C%2Fcqi-pmi-ConfigIndex%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ccqi-FormatIndicatorPeriodic%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CwidebandCQI%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fcqi-FormatIndicatorPeriodic%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cri-ConfigIndex%3E322%3C%2Fri-ConfigIndex%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3CsimultaneousAckNackAndCQI%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cfalse%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FsimultaneousAckNackAndCQI%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fsetup%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fcqi-ReportPeriodic%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fcqi-ReportConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++%3CantennaInfo%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3CexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CtransmissionMode%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ctm3%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FtransmissionMode%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3CcodebookSubsetRestriction%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cn2TxAntenna-tm3%3E11%3C%2Fn2TxAntenna-tm3%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FcodebookSubsetRestriction%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cue-TransmitAntennaSelection%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Crelease%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fue-TransmitAntennaSelection%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FexplicitValue%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FantennaInfo%3E++++++++++++++++++%3CschedulingRequestConfig%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3Csetup%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csr-PUCCH-ResourceIndex%3E0%3C%2Fsr-PUCCH-ResourceIndex%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Csr-ConfigIndex%3E13%3C%2Fsr-ConfigIndex%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cdsr-TransMax%3E++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cn64%2F%3E++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fdsr-TransMax%3E++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fsetup%3E++++++++++++++++++%3C%2FschedulingRequestConfig%3E++++++++++++++++%3C%2FphysicalConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++++%3C%2FradioResourceConfigDedicated%3E++++++++++++%3C%2FrrcConnectionSetup-r8%3E++++++++++%3C%2Fc1%3E++++++++%3C%2FcriticalExtensions%3E++++++%3C%2FrrcConnectionSetup%3E++++%3C%2Fc1%3E++%3C%2Fmessage%3E%3C%2FDL-CCCH-Message%3E")'>RRC_RRC_CONNECTION_SETUP</a></td>
```

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to determine what causes this issue, I did find out that the XML links open fine in Firefox ESR 52.1.0 in Windows 7, so I installed that for the user.  I'm guessing something in the newer browsers blocks this functionality for some security reason.